# Composer - download package from private gitlab package registry - invalid credentials

Tags: authentication, gitlab, composer-php, satis, personal-access-token

I have a small pipeline to use a custom composer package into a project:

- the private gitlab project generates a composer package and publish it to the project package registry: this works all fine
- a second private project use satis to generate a repository with the first project package and publish the resulting build folder to the project gitlab pages: this too wortks fine (all the packages versions are visible from the web ui), the project pages permission is set to  'Only project members'
- last, the main project uses composer to download my package from the satis repo: here i'm getting the error

  ```
  Invalid credentials for 'https://gitlab.com/users/sign_in', aborting.
  ```

I added an entry in the `repositories` section of composer.json and added gitlab credentals with composer cli command

##### `composer.json` 'repositories' entry

```json
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://gitlab.com/vendor/group/project"
    }
]
```

##### composer cli command for credentials

```
composer config gitlab-token.gitlab.com glpat-123456789abcdefgh
```

##### `auth.json` generated by composer cli

```json
{
    "gitlab-token": {
        "gitlab.com": "glpat-123456789abcdefgh"
    }
}
```

##### error during `composer require`

```
Invalid credentials for 'https://gitlab.com/users/sign_in', aborting.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i did found a wrong documentation page.

According to [Install a Composer package](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/composer_repository/#install-a-composer-package) the correct composer cli command to add the repository entry in `composer.json` is

```
composer config repositories.<group_id> composer https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/group/<group_id>/-/packages/composer/
```

that leads to the entry

```json
"repositories": {
    "<group_id>": {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/group/<group_id>/-/packages/composer/"
    },
    ...
},
```